# How to create an iOS application news that updates daily

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

What I want to do is an iOS app news, that shows images and some text that describes the image. Just like '9GAG' that has an image and some text below that describes the image. This app has to update the content every time new news appears. And when the user clicks on the image appears a paragraph of the news.  How do I get the app to update daily without the users having to re download or manually update the app? I really don't know how to do it, do I have to connect to a database or a website? Please help!

Thank you very much.

Comment: Depends on if you're connecting to a 3rd party provider for this news you speak of. If you control this news yourself manually, then perhaps a simple property list on a hosting provider such as Amazon S3 will suffice perfectly.

Comment: Sure, I'm going to control this news. When I want to publish a new news my app has to update. How do I do that?

Comment: By update, do you mean send a push notification to the user, and let them decide if they want to open the app, or update as in whenever the app comes into the foreground every time.

Comment: Yes the second one. Whenever the app comes into the foreground every time. Just exactly like '9GAG', when you open '9GAG' app you see new news every time right? I want to do that. Every time I want to publish new news, users can see them without re download the app.

Comment: Yes, this is easy and fun to do using property lists. Let me try to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your App Delegate, create a property to hold an NSDictionary that you can later access anywhere in your app (for example a UITableViewController)

AppDelegate.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *dictionary;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://foobar.com/news.plist"]];
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData;
    request.timeoutInterval = 5.0;

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:
     ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         if (data)
         {
             NSPropertyListFormat format;

             self.dictionary = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:data options:NSPropertyListImmutable format:&format error:nil];

            // Todo: post an NSNotification to any other view controllers telling them that we have the new data.

         }
         else
         {
             // Tell user connection failed
         }
     }];
}
```

Comment: Where should I have my pictures and news that I want to publish on my app?

Comment: A UITableView is one of the best ways to display content of this type, it even allows you to have pull to refresh with no special work needed.

Comment: But from where will I supposed to upload my images? From a database? Server?

Comment: Sign up for Amazon S3. You can upload through a web browser, and it's easy.

Comment: You're welcome. Up vote my answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

How about adding timer and refreshing your app periodically at specific timeinerval